# Apache crashes due to bots

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, apache-2.4, lamp

I am running a LAMP stack on an AWS Ubuntu server. Every now and then (perhaps once a week, once every other week) Apache will crash and the site will go down. Looking at the Apache error logs, I have noticed that these crashes usually happen when a bot tries to brute force our site. For example, today it tried to acces wp-login.php. Our site is not using Wordpress. So my questions are...

1) Why does accessing wp-login.php cause Apache to crash? Shouldn't the bot simply recieve a 404 error?

2) How can I prevent these malicious bots from accessing/crashing my site? I would obviously like to blacklist any requests to /admin, /wp-admin.php, etc.

Please forgive me if this is too vague or a bad question. I am new to ServerFault (and by extension, server administration and web development, in general).

Answer (score 2):

Bots looking for vulnerabilities, denial of service, or credential stuffing do not care what you are running, or if their scans are not gentle on your system. They will brute force everything they have as fast as possible.

---

Review logs to determine why it crashed.

Perhaps it fell over due to insufficient resources, such as the Linux OOM killer. Do a capacity analysis. Ensure that allocated resources (memory) are more than peak possible utilization (Apache MPM tuning + database shared memory).

Possibly there is a crash bug somewhere in your software stack. Apply software updates. Enable logging in the application. Check that crash dumps are enabled, and review any. Identify where it is dying: in the web application, a language runtime, or some other library.

And if this is still fragile, put it behind some additional filtering. Such as a web application firewall.

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, what can I research to learn how to do these things? As in, is there a broader term to describe these techniques? Thank you!

Comment: I already outlined some ideas in general terms. Root cause analysis is a core sysadmin skill. Gather information and learn the system  until you understand what failed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have your web server hardened to cope with whatever the internet throws at it.

Three key tools I use for this are rate limiting, CloudFlare, and fail2ban.

**CloudFlare**

CloudFlare filters out the worst of the bad traffic, such as a DDOS. It also has a firewall you can alter using an API, which I'll go into shortly.

**Fail2Ban**

With Fail2ban you define rules about what are "not good" and "bad" actions. Fail2ban takes actions based on this - for example immediately banning users who do bad things, and banning users after three "not good things".

Fail2ban usually changes the local firewall like iptables to ban traffic getting to the web server. This is effective but you still have to pay for the traffic. An alternate approach is to have fail2ban call the CloudFlare API to firewall traffic on the edge, before it hits your server.

I have an article on how to do that [here](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/aws-amazon-web-services/protecting-amazon-linux-server-fail2ban-cloudflare-wordpress/).

**Rate Limiting**

Nginx has rate limiting built in, and I assume Apache does as well. It can rate limit in a variety of ways, but by IP is easiest. Have a look at the Apache documentation.